# FTP user not able to see or access anything?

Tags: linux, ftp, chmod, chown

I am trying to make an FTP account for a user, and it is not working.  The user wants to be able to ftp to his sites home directory, and change stuff.  I created a user(MEvans) and set the home directory to /var/www/html/domain.co.uk .  In terminal, I type `ftp localhost`, then the users name, then password, and it says `230 Login successful.`  I then try the `ls` command, and it says

```
227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,169,60)
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Transfer done (but failed to open directory).
```

What is wrong?  The ownership of the domain.co.uk folder is MEvans, and the permissions for the folder and its contents are (temporarily, this site is not live) set to 777.

Comment: Have you checked any of the log files?  increased the logging to find the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a distribution based on Red Hat(CentOS, Scientific Linux, Fedora) then it's probably SELINUX that's causing this issue. A workaround would be to set `SELINUX=disabled` in /etc/selinux/config.

If you want to continue using SELINUX then I'd suggest you head over to http://selinuxproject.org/page/FTPRecipes.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I actually do not even work at that company anymore, so I have no idea if that works.  Thanks for taking the time to answer anyways!